# Many selects from different tables and not show result if nothing found

Tags: mysql

I have many tables and some of them have column 'Item'. I want to make easy query,which allow me to check in which table or tables i can find item with number which i want.
I have read some info about variable and made this:

```
SET @Item_id =(there i put number) ;
select * from table1 where item=@Item_id;
select * from table2 where item=@Item_id;
select * from table3 where item=@Item_id;
select * ...(other tables)
```

Problem is my DBMS will show tabs with result for each table and it doesn't matter if search was successful or not.
How can i update code to show me tables only with results ?

```
SET @Item_id = 29434;
SELECT
(select distinct item from creature_loot_template where item=@Item_id)  as table1
(select distinct item from gameobject_loot_template  where item=@Item_id) as table2
(select distinct item from item_loot_template where item=@Item_id) as table3
```

Comment: What tool do you use to connect and run queries through?  Tabs aren't a MySQL feature Thus your DBMS has nothing to do with the tabs. (For instance, I connect via a commandline, which has no tabs, and Navicat,  which is a GUI and has tabs)

Comment: I use Navicat most time.

Comment: Do you want the results to be combined into one single results table?

Comment: Yes and i need to know from which table did they come.

Answer (score 0):

This may not do exactly what you want, but for instances like this, I usually use the union option to dump the results from all the queries into one single table.  To show which query or source table it came from, I make a fake column with a string constant.

```
SET @Item_id =(there i put number) ;
select 'table1', * from table1 where item=@Item_id union
select 'table2', * from table2 where item=@Item_id union
select 'table3', * from table3 where item=@Item_id;
```

Comment: Well,union works,but i need to know from which table i got them.What did you mean about fake column ?

Comment: Look directly after the Select. I've hard coded the table name directly into the query so you know the origin of the result

Comment: tell us the error... it's difficult to debug this situation with the information you're giving...

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from creature_loot_template where item=@Item_id union
select 'creature_loot_t' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try Something like this:

```
SET @Item_id =(the Id you want to check) ;
SELECT
(select distinct item from table1 where item=@Item_id) as table1
(select distinct item from table2 where item=@Item_id) as table2
(select distinct item from table3 where item=@Item_id) as table3
...
```

That way, you should have an input like this:

- table1 table2 table3
- null   null   item

Therefore you will know in which table you found your item.

Comment: I have tryed your variant..This gave error.Posted code in top of topic.

Comment: If add ; to the end for each select then will be no error,but query works only for first select from creature_loot_template. I tried using 2 unions between selects,but no luck - only first row using.

Comment: If remove all Distinct then will error Subquery returns more than 1 row